# Pytorch: Index with tensor along multiple axes OR scatter to more than one index at once

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, pytorch

I am trying to update very specific indices of a multidimensional tensor in Pytorch, and I am not sure how to access the correct indices. I can do this in a very straightforward way in Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
#set up the array containing the data
data = 100*np.ones((10,10,2))
data[5:,:,:] = 0
#select the data points that I want to update
idxs = np.nonzero(data.sum(2))
#generate the updates that I am going to do
updates = np.random.randint(5,size=(idxs[0].shape[0],2))
#update the data
data[idxs[0],idxs[1],:] = updates
```

I need to implement this in Pytorch but I am not sure how to do this. It seems like I need the `scatter` function but that only works along a single dimension instead of the multiple dimensions that I need. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These operations work exactly the same in their PyTorch counterparts, except for [`torch.nonzero`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.nonzero), which by default returns a tensor of size *[z, n]* (where *z* is the number of non-zero elements and *n* the number of dimensions) instead of a tuple of *n* tensors with size *[z]* (as NumPy does), but that behaviour can be changed by setting `as_tuple=True`.

Other than that you can directly translate it to PyTorch, but you need to make sure that the types match, because you cannot assign a tensor of type `torch.long` (default of `torch.randint`) to a tensor of type `torch.float` (default of `torch.ones`). In this case, `data` is probably meant to have type `torch.long`:

```py
#set up the array containing the data
data = 100*torch.ones((10,10,2), dtype=torch.long)
data[5:,:,:] = 0
#select the data points that I want to update
idxs = torch.nonzero(data.sum(2), as_tuple=True)
#generate the updates that I am going to do
updates = torch.randint(5,size=(idxs[0].shape[0],2))
#update the data
data[idxs[0],idxs[1],:] = updates
```

Comment: I see, I was used to the Tensorfow convention of doing all of this with gather_nd, scatter_nd, etc